# Deserializing a Enum with Jackson in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, enums, jackson

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize an enum with Jackson.

My enum:

```
public enum class Type {
    @JsonProperty("Typ A")
    TypeA,
    @JsonProperty("Typ B")
    TypeB,
}
```

Serializing Type.TypeA results in the desired outcome of "Typ A". However Deserializing "Typ A" results in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant de.advisori.pzp.task.TaskType.Typ A
```

I have tried other variations that I found online, such as this:

```
public enum class Type (@JsonValue val value: String) {
    TypeA("Typ A"),
    TypeB("Typ B"),
}
```

but they all yield the same result. Serialization works, deserialization results in the error above.

How do I correctly deserialize an enum with Jackson?

If it makes any difference: I am using it in a Spring Boot `RequestMapping` as a `@RequestParam` and return value.

Comment: I can't help with Jackson, but if you don't find a better answer, maybe you can take advantage of Kotlin's ability to include spaces in names: `public enum class Type { \`Typ A\`, \`Typ B\` }`

Comment: If you share the rest of that stack trace, I'm guessing you'll find Jackson is not involved in this particular deserialization, and you'll need to configure Spring to do the conversion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053897/deserialize-requestparam-enum-case-insensitive-in-spring-boot-using-jackson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate enum fields for deserialization using Jackson json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300191/how-to-annotate-enum-fields-for-deserialization-using-jackson-json)

Comment: Take a look at that question: [Serialize @JsonProperty value of enum to @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030789/serialize-jsonproperty-value-of-enum-to-requestparam)

Comment: @dnault Yes, indeed, it seems RequestParams are treated as raw values and not as JSON that could be deserialized. Hence `@JsonProperty` can only be used on a RequestBody. I ended up using @DodgyCodeException s "solution" of using enums with spaces, as it seemed the best fit for my current application. For anyone else coming across this in the future, the question suggested by @Michal Ziober seems to have a good answer for defining an explicit converter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69031139/12898394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dnault pointed out, Jackson isn't used for deserialization here. `@RequestParams` are never treated as JSON, hence Jackson is never used on them.

Two possible solutions are:

- Using Kotlins ability to use spaces in names:
  `` public enum class Type { `Typ A`, `Typ B` } `` (suggested by @DodgyCodeException)
- Using a explicitly defined converter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69031139/12898394 (pointed in the right direction by @Michal Ziober

Answer (score -1):

I don't think any annotations will work to change the enum values.  For this you need to write your own Serializer and Deserializer.

You will likely want to do this:

1. Create a Serializer by subclassing `StdSerializer`
2. Create a Deserializer by subclassing `StdDeserializer`
3. If you intend on using the enum as a key in JSON you will need `KeyDeserializer` too
4. Create a Module to wrap these up that you can pass to the configuration of Jackson, for that you use `SimpleModule`

There are many tutorials for this, e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: Downvoted because Jackson annotations can indeed alter how enum values are serialized and deserialized by Jackson.